# Dual boot, elementary OS not detecting windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to dual boot on my laptop Win 10 and elementary OS on the same SSD. The problem is when I go to install elementary OS (something else option) my Win 10 partition doesn't appear so I cannot continue, otherwise I would wipe the Win 10 installation.

Is there something that I'm missing? I've done it before without any problem, just used the option of "install it alongside Windows".

By the way, secure boot is disabled and the partition for elementary OS isn't formatted (Unallocated).

Thanks,

tl,dr I haven't found any similar question here but if it's duplicated, please remove after pointing me in the right direction please! Noob here.

Answer (score 0):

Read your question wrong just select install something else and make your own partitions a swap 2x ram and rest to /

Comment: could you edit the answer to make it clearer what you're saying? At least add some punctuation :)

Comment: Sorry, writing from my phone. What part don't you understand?

Comment: Wouldn't this wipe the windows partition?

Comment: no because you're setting your own partitions so you can clearly see from the partition table that windows will be dev/sda#

Answer (score -1):

You can find some answers in my article on https://kaneis.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/installation-of-ubuntu-dual-boot-windows-already-installed-on-sony-vaio-svs13a1s9es-13-5-laptop-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-the-process-that-follows-assume-that-we-have-a-x86_64-system-64bit/

Comment: No propaganda please